# Error in ctype conversion with text box on e.control

Tags: vb.net

I'm using textbox keyUp event in text box in datagridview my code looks like this

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    

    If e.Control IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        Dim quantity As TextBox = CType(e.Control, TextBox)
        RemoveHandler quantity.KeyUp, AddressOf quantity_KeyUp
        AddHandler quantity.KeyUp, AddressOf quantity_KeyUp

    End If

    If e.Control IsNot Nothing AndAlso DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        Dim cmb As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        RemoveHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Cmb_SelectedIndexChanged
        AddHandler cmb.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf Cmb_SelectedIndexChanged
    End If
End Sub
```

here combobox code works fine but in textbox control I'm facing an error `Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error   BC30311 Value of type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'TextBox'`

What's wrong here

Comment: Is it a name clash? Do you have another type named `TextBox` that does not inherit `Control`? Try Ctrl+clicking on that type name and see where it takes you.

Comment: TextBox is system ui text box when I Ctrl+click it takes me to the Syste.webui.WebControls page

Comment: Why would you have a reference to `System.Web.UI.WebControls` in a Windows Froms application? Remove it

Comment: I basically want to calculate total price which is last column in dgv. so when user trype quantity in textbox of dgv it has to count total amount how can i do this any way to do this??

Comment: Then your issue is exactly what I said. In your code, `e.Control` is type `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. Exactly as the error message says, that cannot be cast as type `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox`. It can be cast as type `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`, which is what you obviously intended, but you have imported a namespace specific to Web Forms for no discernible reason and broken your app as a result. Get rid of that import and get rid of the assembly reference that allows you to add it and your code will work as you want.

Comment: Ohh my god that one import line even I don't know from where it get broken my code. Thanks alot man thanks

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer